# finding distance between two points in python, passing inputs via two different objects

Tags: python, class, methods

I have to write a code to find the different between two point by passing value via two objects as below.
But I am getting TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', and 'z'

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return '(point: {},{},{})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt( (self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2 + (self.z -other.z)**2 )      


p = Point()

p1 = Point(12, 3, 4)

p2 = Point(4, 5, 6)

p3 = Point(-2, -1, 4)

print(p.distance(p1,p3))
```

Comment: You gave no arguments to `p = Point()` the next 3 are fine

Comment: one line is missing in code ..proivded full code below..

Comment: class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return '(point: {},{},{})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)
        
    def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt( (self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2 + (self.z -other.z)**2 )
        
        
     
p = Point()
p1 = Point(12, 3, 4)
p2 = Point(4, 5, 6)
p3 = Point(-2, -1, 4)
print(p.distance(p1,p3))

Comment: Also as written you should really be calling like `p1.distance(p3)`

Comment: As said by @CoryKramer you don't have arguments for `p`. Also, you don't need this point, if you want distance between `p1` and `p3`, you should get it by `p1.distance(p3)`

Comment: @JeniferJ edit the question with the full code, in a comment is poorly readable

Comment: how distance method taken 2 values and assigned p1 values for x,y,z and another p3 values for other.x, other.y and other.z?

Comment: i have created p = point() ..object p to access the method distance in the class point. Is that the wrong way to call methods inside the class?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this line:

```
p = Point()
```

When you defined you class, you specified it has to be passed 3 parameters for it to be initialised (`def __init__(self, x, y,z)`).

If you still want to be able to create this Point object without having to pass those 3 parameters, you can make them optional like this :

```
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
```

This way, if you were to not specify these parameters (as you did), it will create a point with coordinates {0, 0, 0} by default.

Comment: Thanks..i am just learning via online courses..this is a new learning for me today..thanks much

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the required 3 arguments for `p = Point()`

fixed your errors

```
from math import sqrt
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return '(point: {},{},{})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt( (self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2 + (self.z -other.z)**2 )      


# p = Point() # not required

p1 = Point(12, 3, 4)

p2 = Point(4, 5, 6)

p3 = Point(-2, -1, 4)

print(p1.distance(p3)) # use this to find distance between p1 and any other point

# or use this
print(Point.distance(p1,p3))
```

Comment: Thanks..i am just learning via online courses..this is a new learning for me today..thanks much

Answer (score 0):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return '(point: {},{},{})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def distance(self, other):
        return math.sqrt( (self.x-other.x)**2 + (self.y-other.y)**2 + (self.z -other.z)**2 )

p1 = Point(12, 3, 4)

p2 = Point(4, 5, 6)

p3 = Point(-2, -1, 4)

print(Point.distance(p1,p3))
```

It works like this.You should not define a `P` point seperate than the other three points. Every point is a seperate instance. But when you try to use the function just call the class.